# Как использовать numpy.sum для вычисления суммы произведений списка?

Tags: python, оптимизация, numpy

Допустим, есть список. В цикле `for` с количеством итераций равным длине списка минус `m`, где `m` равно к примеру 20, а длина списка 80, я могу вычислить сумму произведений `X[i]*X[i+m]`, где `X` - идентификатор списка, `i` - переменная счётчик, в списке хранятся значения типа `float`.

То есть, например:

```
for i in range(len(X)-m):
    res = res + X[i]*X[i+m]
```

Как с помощью `numpy.sum()` можно решить эту задачу?

Comment: я имею в виду количество итераций = длина списка - m, в цикле это указано как len(X)-m

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Поскольку другой ответ на самом деле считает неправильно (индексы неправильно берутся), привожу правильный вариант, с проверкой:

```
import numpy as np

n = 80
m = 20
X = np.random.rand(n)
res = 0

for i in range(len(X)-m):
    res = res + X[i]*X[i+m] 
print(res)

print(np.sum(np.multiply(X[:-m], X[m:])))
# или тоже самое np.sum(X[:-m] * X[m:])
```

Можно убедиться, что оба варианта подсчёта дают [почти] одинаковый результат (+/- в последних знаках).

Answer (score 3):

Эту задачу можно решить вызовом одной функции и без предварительного умножения векторов:

```
res = np.dot(X[:-m], X[m:])
```

проверка:

```
In [40]: np.dot(X[:-m], X[m:])
Out[40]: 16.34584647089808

In [41]: np.sum(np.multiply(X[:-m], X[m:]))
Out[41]: 16.34584647089808

In [42]: np.sum(X[:len(X)-m] * X[m:])
Out[42]: 16.34584647089808
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте срезы:

```
np.sum(X[:len(X) - m] * X[m:])
```

Comment: `len(X)-m` опять же писать не обязательно, срезы понимают `-m` именно как то, что вы написали